# Merge application.yml from main app and integration test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to merge application.yml properties from main app and integration tests so that in the the end we will get all properties from the main file + only overridden properties:

main application.yml:

```
# list of database related properties...
info:
  app:
    name: name
    description: description
    version: 1.0.0
```

integration tests application.yml:

```
info:
  app:
    description: new description
```

So finally I need to get:

```
# list of database related properties...
info:
  app:
    name: name
    description: new description
    version: 1.0.0
```

Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'info.app.description' in value ${info.app.description}

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT name second set of properties `application.yml` but rather `application-test.yml` and then activate `test` profile in your tests eg using `@ActiveProfile('test')` or any other method of setting active profiles.

Then you have factor in how you run your test, where configuration files are placed (in the classpath or external), if any customization of config files has been made or not etc.

Comment: Since that solves the issue, consider accepting my answer so rep can grow;)